# Possible to have sub Collections in Collection?

Tags: backbone.js

I am learning `Backbone.js` and try to develop revamp a project using `Backbong.js`. As the project was already have APIs and was using in different platforms, iphone app, andorid app and web.

My problem is, there is a API return as below

```
{
     success: true,
     response: {
         posts: [{...post data...}, {...post data...}, {...post data...}],
         users: [{...user data...}, {...user data...}],
         categories: [{...category data...}, {...category data...}]
     }
}
```

as the backbone documentation

a `Collection` can contain many models

Typically the design is

```
// Post Model
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
})

// User Model
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
})

// Category Model
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
})

var PostListCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: PostModel 
})
```

So... How can I put these 3 types of "objects" in the a Collection? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unsure why you'd want a collection that isn't a single collection.  It sounds like (and do correct me if this is wrong), you want a neat way of fetching your data from the API and turning it in to your three collections.

You could create a model that fetches from your API, that implements a custom `parse` function to create three collections within it.
Granted, you'll want to define `UserCollection`, `PostCollection` and `CategoryCollection` beforehand.

```
ApplicationModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/apiUrl/',
    parse: function(data)
    {
         var result = {};
         result.users = new UserCollection(data.users);
         result.posts= new PostCollection(data.posts);
         result.categories = new CategoryCollection(data.categories);
         return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: How if i am going to query next page the that main collection?

Comment: Note that whenever ApplicationModel fetches, whether it be a new page or otherwise, parse will be called.

Answer (score 2):

you can have a model that contain the collections

```
var ResultModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    default: {
       Users: [],
       Posts: [],
       Categories: []
    }
});
```

Then implements the collection in usual way.

So, when you try to get the child collections ...

```
var result = new ResultModel("your result JSON object");
var users = new UserCollection(result.get("Users"));
var posts = new PostCollection(result.get("Posts"));
var categories = new CategoryCollection(result.get("Category"));
```

This is working well for me ... in my case